# Cannot assign a value of type 'String!' to a value of type 'AnyObject?' - Xcode and parse

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

I am running the following code:

```
    var inventario = PFQuery(className:"InventarioObjetos")
    inventario.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(toPassID) {
        (inventario: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error!)
        } else {
            inventario["Categoria"] = self.nuevoCategoria.text
            inventario["Descripcion"] = self.nuevoDescripcion.text
            inventario["Tamano"] = self.tamano.text

            // Guarda la fecha de entrada
            let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            let d = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(self.nuevoFechaDeEntrada.text)
            inventario["FechaDeEntrada"] = d

        }
    }
```

And on the `inventario["Tamano"] = self.tamano.text` line, I get this error:

> Cannot assign a value of type 'String!' to a value of type 'AnyObject?'

Answer (score 0):

Just cast `self.tamano.text` to an `AnyObject`: `inventario["Tamano"] = self.tamano.text as! AnyObject`

Comment: self.nuevoCategoria.text = self.timelineData[0].objectForKey("Categoria") as? String

Comment: What is the type of `inventario`? `[String:AnyObject]`?

Comment: var inventario = PFQuery(className:"InventarioObjetos")
            inventario.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(toPassID) {
                (inventario: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

Comment: No, its type, like the type of `dateStringFormatter` is `NSDateFormatter` and the type of `error` is `NSError`.

Comment: I think it is of class PFQuery

Comment: Oh, you're right, I just wasn't reading it well enough. Are you sure the `inventario` has a `tamano` field?

Comment: Yes. The program was running perfect until I upgraded to swift 1.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87543/discussion-between-iliketau-and-jesus-guerrero-almaraz).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
inventario["Tamano"] = self.tamano.text? (as! AnyObject?) shouldn't need this
```

Actually I would add the "?" in all your conversions just in case the user left one empty or a check like

```
if let strTamano = self.tamano.text{
   inventario["Tamano"] = strTamano
} else { println("error converting tamano") }
```

of course the println would popup a dialog or do something more useful to the final user.

Comment: I get error Cannot assign a value of type 'String!' to a value of type 'UITextField?'

Comment: No. It does not work. I have the following lines above

Comment: self.tamano.text = self.timelineData[0].objectForKey("Tamano") as? String

Comment: the error in swift is probably a wrong description of the problem, I think your problem is that your string is actually empty, try print it to console before assigned to the array from parse, however if you had use the if let as I suggest it should had stop the error.